# Is it possible to load url inside a div through jquery without using iframe, object, embed html tags?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test page</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="My-page" style="width:900px; height:900px; position: absolute;overflow-x:hidden !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;" class="iframely-widget-container">
<script>$("#My-page").load("http://www.flipbeets.com/display-embed-code/ZG9sY2VnYWJiYW5h/OTAwcHg=/OTAwcHg=/MQ==/MQ==/MQ==");</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to load url inside a div through jquery without using iframe, object, embed html tags?

Comment: it is possible if cross domain allowed on URL which you want to load.

Comment: see this example http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/5695/

Comment: Refer http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible if cross domain allowed on URL which you want to load.

see this example [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/5695/)

```
  <div id="My-page" style="width:900px; height:900px; position: absolute;overflow-x:hidden !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;" class="iframely-widget-container">
```

```
$("#My-page").load("http://fiddle.jshell.net");
```

Comment: your code is  working, but in the  same example when i trying to load flipbeets.com  it is not loading . with iframe it is working when using jquery .load("http://flipbeets.com") it is not loading i did'nt understand what is the  exact problem , can u explain me

Comment: @Chanukya   rad my comment .. it will not work in cross domain policy. if domain not allow cross domain request then it will not work .

Comment: in frame we did'nt get any cross domain policy issues ,

Comment: tyr this code with PHP in side your My-page.
<?php
$d =   file_get_contents('http://www.flipbeets.com/display-embed-code/ZG9sY2VnYWJiYW5h/OTAwcHg=/OTAwcHg=/MQ==/MQ==/MQ==');
        echo $d;    ?>

Comment: when using  .load("url ") getting cross domain policy issues ,

Comment: iframe is different thing. with use of any javascript/jquery function they use ajax request and from client side request on different server it will not allow

Comment: i dont know y iframe is loading any external site in my page, but .load() can't

Comment: if my answer is useful to you you can mark or upvote.. according to your question what ever is suggest is correct .. cross domain never allow you to load data

Comment: ur answer helpful to me , i understand what u told about cross domain issue thanks @jquery

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use "$.get" and here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vilaskumkar/ndvsa6xc/)

```
$.get( "http://vilaskumkar.github.io", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: @Vilash Kumar question is not about load javascript file

Comment: it will not work with domains which is not allow cross domain request .try with google.com ?

Comment: Agreed!!!
Then I guess user needs to use something like this http://www.whateverorigin.org/